# Xamarin iOS Designer xib missing 'Files Owner', 'ViewController' objects in Document Outline

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am a Xamarin beginner working on a cross platform mobile project using [MvvmCross](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross).

I just upgraded to Xcode 7 and Xamarin Studio 5.10 and trying to use older iOS xib files in [Xamarin iOS Designer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/designer/) instead of Xcode.

Although the xib does't have a view controller object, previously, when the xib opened in Xcode 6, I could connect the outlets directly to the `Files Owner` which is missing in the Designer (see image below).

I have 2 questions

1. Why do the view controller xibs created in MvvmCross do not contain the `ViewController` object
2. How can I access 'Files Owner' in the Xamarin iOS Designer?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having some issues finding it I too thought it had been missed out of Xamarin Studio. Instead of clicking on the white area, click on the grey background the surrounds the view. The option to set the file's owner will then appear in the properties pane ->
[image: The Xamarin Studio UI showing files owner]

Comment: I too figured this out eventually. Designer has a loooong way to go .... Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Thank you so much mate, I was looking for this for 2 days and I was going crazy. I'll keep using IB to visually create my views though, things like this make me waste way too much time when using Xamarin